# jQuery Validate Refactoring

Tags: jquery, refactoring, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and am running into a refactoring issue.  I have a javascript function that creates `<li>`'s based on a drop-down number.

The resulting `<li>`'s are generated as:

```
<li class="person-information hide" style="display: list-item; ">
<!-- First Name -->
<input type="text" class="person-name-first error" name="person-name-first">
<!-- Last Name -->
<input type="text" class="person-name-last" name="person-name-last">
<!-- Age -->
<select class="person-age valid" name="person-age">
<option value="1">Infant/Toddler (1-3)</option>
<option value="2">Child (4-17)</option>
<option value="3">Adult (18+)</option>
</select>
</li>
```

I then have my validate rules, using addMethod and addClassRules

```
$.validator.addMethod("fNameRequired", $.validator.methods.required, "First Name Required");
$.validator.addMethod("fNameMinlength", $.validator.methods.minlength, $.format("First Name must have at least {0} characters"));
$.validator.addClassRules("person-name-first", { fNameRequired: true, fNameMinlength: 2 });
```

My issue is, the validation error is only thrown on the first element that's generated.  So if I have 5 of the `<li>`'s with the class `"person-name-first"` , it only runs validation on the first element that doesn't pass.  Meaning that the elements that fail below that do not get the 'error' class added, until they've been focused.

Any ideas on how to make it look through all the elements with identical classes that fail?